D3 multiline grafhic Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,346.47LNaN,3…"
Im trying to create a multiline graphic whith D3, in body I have this Line:
<svg id="lineChart1" width="600" height="400"></svg>

this is the js code:
  function getRandomColor() {
      const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      return `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
  }

 

  function createChartD3(selector, labels, datasets) {
      const svg = d3.select(selector);
      const margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40 };
      const width = +svg.attr('width') - margin.left - margin.right;
      const height = +svg.attr('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      const x = d3.scaleTime()
          .domain(d3.extent(labels))
          .range([0, width]);
     

      const y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(datasets, d => d3.max(d.values))])
          .nice()
          .range([height, 0]);

      const line = d3.line()
          .x((d, i) => x(labels[i]))
          .y(d => y(d));

      const g = svg.append('g')
          .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

      
      g.append('g')
          .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height})`)
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      
      g.append('g')
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

      
      datasets.forEach(dataset => {
          g.append('path')
              .datum(dataset.values)
              .attr('class', 'line')
              .attr('d', line)
              .attr('stroke', getRandomColor())
              .attr('fill', 'none');
      });
  }

this is what I'm passing to function:
selector:'lineChart1'

label is an array of dates
['2024-10-13T09:40:06',
'2024-10-13T09:40:21',
'2024-10-13T09:40:36]

dataset is an array of object with this props {label:'string', value:'Array'}
es:
[{label:'CH_01', values:[7287.385, 7510.846, 7590.083, 7544.071, 7681.146, 7467.861, 7432.631, 7392.977]},
[{label:'CH_02', values: [3871.76, 4000.862, 4106.523, 4124.878, 4145, 3944.293, 4054.519, 4048.956, 3970.813, 4017.163, 4116.421]}]

I have a lot of data two minutes contains approx 5600 record so 5600 dates as label and 5600 values in each array(values) in dataset multiplied 14 times (there are 14 objects in datasets)
I tried to change some values but I don't understand what is wrong.

Your x-scale is a time scale but you are giving it an array of strings not dates.  You need to convert those strings to JavaScript date objects.  Use timeParse if the date/times are local or utcParse if in UTC.
const tp = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
labels = labels.map(label => tp(label));




 // Sample label and dataset
        const labels = ['2024-10-13T09:40:06', '2024-10-13T09:40:21', '2024-10-13T09:40:36'];
        const datasets = [
            {
                label: 'CH_01',
                values: [7287.385, 7510.846, 7590.083]
            },
            {
                label: 'CH_02',
                values: [3871.76, 4000.862, 4106.523]
            }
        ];

        // Function to generate a random color
        function getRandomColor() {
            const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
            const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
            const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
            return `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
        }

        // Function to create a multiline chart with D3
        function createChartD3(selector, labels, datasets) {
            const svg = d3.select(selector);
            const margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40 };
            const width = +svg.attr('width') - margin.left - margin.right;
            const height = +svg.attr('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom;


            // X scale: time scale
            const x = d3.scaleTime()
                .domain(d3.extent(labels, d=> new Date(d)))
                .range([0, width]);
            
            // Y scale: linear scale for datasets' values
            const y = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(datasets, d => d3.max(d.values))])
                .nice()
                .range([height, 0]);

            // Line generator function
            const line = d3.line()
                .x((d, i) => x(new Date(labels[i])))
                .y(d => y(d));

            // Group for chart content
            const g = svg.append('g')
                .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

            // X-axis
            g.append('g')
                .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height})`)
                .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

            // Y-axis
            g.append('g')
                .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

            // Plot each dataset's line
            datasets.forEach(dataset => {
                g.append('path')
                    .datum(dataset.values)
                    .attr('class', 'line')
                    .attr('d', line)
                    .attr('stroke', getRandomColor())
                    .attr('fill', 'none');
            });
        }

        // Call the function to create the chart
        createChartD3('#lineChart1', labels, datasets);
  .line {
            fill: none;
            stroke-width: 2px;
        }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="lineChart1" width="600" height="400"></svg>



